# How to measure stack memory in Java?

Tags: java, jvm, stack-overflow

There is a single core class that is used in transaction engine. I did a test with high number of concurrent transaction which resulted in a deadly stack-overflow exception. I would like to know if there is any way to measure how much stack memory is available in order to avoid the exception.

I am looking into a dynamic way of doing it as setting a hard limit on the number of concurrent transactions is not ideal.

Comment: You can increase it but you cannot measure how much is used.  The default usually allows 1000-4000 levels of nesting and if you have this many I suggest you change your code to have less rather than increase the limit.  There is no good reason a few transactions or even hundreds of nested transaction should cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give Java VisualVM a try. It's from Oracle, and included with the JDK. You can find it here:

```
${JDK}/bin/jvisualvm.exe
```

Almost anything you want to know about your Java application's performance can be observed through this.

[Here's](http://visualvm.java.net/api-quickstart.html) a quick tutorial if you need it, although it doesn't actually need much of an explanation.

Comment: This tool is very useful for analysis. Not much help if I am to make a dynamic solution.

Comment: Not much of a help when your Java process is sitting on a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Stack Size of a Java program by using the `-Xss` argument (or `"-XX:ThreadStackSize` see [Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)).

But, once set, the **Java stack size cannot be changed dynamically**.

Comment: I have a feeling that stack size may not be changed dynamically. That it's set to OS default if not set. Though, your answer here made me challenge it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358011/how-to-verify-if-java-thread-size-is-fixed-or-limited.