# How to verify if Java thread stack size is fixed or limited?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory

I'm trying to verify if Java stack size is fixed (set at the beginning) or limited (grows to a certain limit). I'm trying to measure this with a simple program that creates a certain amount of threads (with set Xss) but so far I only discovered that RSS is per process and for obvious reasons knowing heap size is meaningless here.

Comment: Instead of creating X threads, how about calling a recursive function to see how large each thread's stack is.  If you could the stacks then you can see if this count changes once you load 1000 threads versus 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle and OpenJDK stack sizes are fixed and do not shrink or grow.
Depending on the platform, default sizes vary.

IBM J9 handles this differently: Stack sizes are limited via a lower and upper boundary for Java Threads. OS threads can have a different stack size.

In case you want to estimate the total size of memory used, you'll have to know the number of threads being used, as the stack sizes are per thread on both Oracle/OpenJDK and on J9.

Comment: Upvoted for J9 vs OpenJDK/Hotspot. I know about thread number and I can have this via a bit of shell magic (starting with jstack or ps). Do you remember your source for fixed stack sizes in JVM? Tried looking in specs but failed to find it there (maybe I'm looking wrong).

Comment: In the end thread size handling is highly OS dependent. I think J9 won't be able to really grow a thread on an OS not supporting this natively.
On beasts like z/OS for instance thread creation using pthread_attr_setstacksize, size is getting specified as minimum size, but upper limit is controlled via other parameters. z/OS has additional increments and upper limits.
On Linux the size of the same method is also a minimum size, but Linux will still create a fixed size thread, which may be larger than the requested size.

Answer (score 1):

J9 (and now Eclipse #OpenJ9) allow the Java stack to grow.  While the native thread's stack is fixed, Java execution occurs on a separate stack which is managed by the JVM.

The Java stack starts small and can grow to a user-configurable limit.